# Cannot vertically-center an image in a navbar item (not brand)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue that I really can't seem to find an answer for. In bootstrap 4's navbar, I'm trying to add an image next to one of the *items* in the navbar (most questions are about the navbar-brand. This isn't it).

With bootstrap4 loaded (and a custom alpha dark them) I have the following right-aligned dropdown:

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/139412744439988224/a_30a390baf654dfe7f1c336037ea481d4.png?size=32" width="28" height="28" class="d-inline-block align-middle rounded-circle" alt=""> 
            Evie.Codes#4611
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <h6 class="dropdown-header"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Evie.Codes</h6>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dashboard</a>

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Admin</a>

            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
          </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

With the image, every menu item  *except* the "brand" part is moved slightly upwards. If I remove the image everything is perfectly centered.

I've created a fiddle that gives *almost* the same behaviour, though for some reason most menu items are centered - they're not in my environment. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ffksbv1v/

Actual Behaviour (red lines for emphasis): 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing `line-height` and `vertical-align` ?

Comment: You use bootstrap with darkly theme. Check that you've added not only darkly css file, but the main bootstrap one too.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure since I can't reproduce it exactly, but I think it may have to do with the fact that the image is bigger then the text.

Also I think that is not the menu that is moved but the nav gets bigger because the padding and everything remains the same but you introduce an image bigger then the text, witch cause the elements to recenter. 
Please note that without the last image the brand height with padding included is exactly the container div height. But after the image is added the brands height+padding is lower than the container div (5.5px) and also lower then the div witch is the parent of the rest of the elements (`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar01">...</div>` - 5px).

So an explication may be that the brand `a` tag is not centered. It doesn't seem exactly centered in the fiddle (just a few pixels difference ~ 5). So I suggest to try to remove the padding from the last `a` element (the one with `nav-link dropdown-toggle` 
 classes - that contains the image and `Evie.Codes#4611`), try add `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom:auto;` to the brand element, or find another way to center the `brand`.